# Database Schema Design For Company vs Account Level Access

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles, access-control, user-accounts

I am working on an application with some basic role based access control. I made a lucid chart of the current design here: https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/49ba4012-c2cc-48de-b11b-5d9c357a66d7

The main objects so far are Accounts, Companies, and Users where a user can be a member of many companies, and there are many companies under 1 account. For example, I can sign up and create a "Bob's Tire Shop" account and I can have several companies under it such as "Bob's Tire Shop in New York" and "Bob's Tire Shop in Chicago", etc.

I want users to be able to be a part of multiple companies, so if Joe is a mechanic at two shops, he should be able to access the info for the the respective shops he works at. I can do this with my current database design, but I am stuck on how to grant account level permissions to a user. For example, when Bob creates the account, he is the account "owner" so he should automatically be able to perform admin actions across all companies. I should also be able to have other "account admins" who can access all companies as well. Or, if I want to give a user "billing" access to an account, he should only be able to see the billing info and not necessarily be a member of the individual companies.

Is it as simple as create an account_users join table between accounts and users with an account_roles table? Or am I missing something else. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the link is not valid anymore. Can you update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create another version of the memberships table that's related to accounts.

This membership_accounts table would store the relationships between accounts and users, and capture the level (account ID, user ID, level). It's essentially the same as the memberships table, but relates to accounts.

The level column in this table would be a foreign key to the memberships_levels table.

Then, to understand a user's full set of permissions, you can get a UNION ALL of both the memberships and membership_accounts tables, and perform your checks on that.

Comment: yes sometimes a user may only need admin access to a few companies. In that case, I was thinking I would create a "memberships" row  (from the lucid chart link I posted) for each of the companies that need access. Does that seem appropriate?

Edit: I updated the lucid chart with your suggestion

Comment: Does a membership determine what level a user can access something? If so, I think the table design can be simplified and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes the membership in a company determines what you can do. There are Reporters in a company who can upload documents, Collaborators inside a company who can upload/edit documents, and Admins in a company who can upload/edit as well as add/remove/edit users in a company. Then at the account level, there should be an Admin who has admin access to all companies in an account and a Billing role who can just login and see billing info.

Comment: Great, I think I understand. I've updated the answer, does that make sense?

Comment: I updated the lucid chart to reflect those changes, but I'm not seeing how the UNION would have a consolidated view of a user's permissions. Are you thinking:


SELECT user_id, account_id, level FROM membership_accounts
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, company_id, level FROM memberships


I'm definitely not a sql expert, so I think I'm missing a piece of the picture as to how that will get me the data I need.

Comment: Or are you thinking more of something like SELECT 'Account' as type, user_id, account_id as id FROM membership_accounts UNION ALL SELECT 'Company', user_id, company_id FROM memberships. This way, the 'type' column would specify what type of membership it is and the generic 'id' column would refer to either the account_id or compnay_id?

Comment: You could do both, depending on your requirements. Having the type in the query would make it easy to see the difference. Or you could use two queries - it's up to you and how your application needs to handle it. But the database design should handle both methods.